# passing javascript to python in GAE

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I am planning to run an app in GAE that initializes the Facebook login sequence in Javascript and passes the access token to a Python script to do server-side work. The javascript looks something like this

```
// Additional init code here

        FB.login(
        function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                var access_token =   FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'];
                console.log('Access Token = '+ access_token);
```

What would be the easiest way to pass access_token to a Python class (say named fbProcessor) that is imported in main.py?

Answer (score 1):

Since the javascript is executed on the front end (client's browser) you can't really "pass" the access_token to python.  You COULD make a http (AJAX) request from javascript to your python app with the access_token.

I think that if you are making a request to python you could just use facebook's [python SDK](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) to retrieve the information (including access token) for the current FB authenticated user... IDK the benefits of either way

the python facebook SDK has google app engine example's

> If you are using the module within a web application with the
>   JavaScript SDK, you can also use the module to use Facebook for login,
>   parsing the cookie set by the JavaScript SDK for logged in users. For
>   example, in Google AppEngine, you could get the profile of the logged
>   in user with:

```
user = facebook.get_user_from_cookie(self.request.cookies, key, secret)
if user:
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(user["access_token"])
    profile = graph.get_object("me")
    friends = graph.get_connections("me", "friends")
```

> You can see a full AppEngine example application in
>   examples/appengine.

Comment: Thanks! What would the AJAX request look like? Just wondering.